# Installing a JavaScript file

Tags: 13.04, default-programs, javascript

Whenever I try to install a JavaScript file it opens it in an editor instead of installing it.  How do I change this action?  Specifically I'm trying to install a script from userscripts.org,

Comment: this is not an ubuntu related question, but Greasemonkey/Firefox related. And it is kind of stupid (from the view of a Webdeveloper, no offence intended).

Answer (score 1):

Thoroughly read the [Installing Greasemonkey Scripts](https://web.archive.org/web/20140502213315/http://userscripts.org/about/installing) guide. Firefox is the browser that is recommended by userscripts.org for using their scripts. Userscripts in Firefox run via the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) Firefox add-on. Greasemonkey allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.

From the Installing Greasemonkey Scripts guide:

> Now that you have Firefox, you need to install Greasemonkey. After installation (which requires restarting your browser), you are now ready to install userscripts.
>
> Now clicking on a .user.js link triggers Greasemonkey to pop up the script installation panel. Greasemonkey shows you a list of what sites the script will run on and ask if you want to install the script.
>
> Now loading a web page results in additional code (the userscript) being run.